# Unity desktop doesn't work, only wallpaper and launcher

Tags: unity, nautilus, icons

My Unity desktop doesn't work after nautilus update. Desktop don't show icon and doesn't do anything on click and right-click.

[image]

I tried this: [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

But don't work for me.

Comment: **Potential close voters:** this is **not** a dupe of this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears

Comment: Can you describe exactly what that "nautilus update" was?

Comment: @CelticWarrior is nautilus update to 3.20.3 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely because Nautilus is replacing your desktop with Gnome-desktop (which it does by default... which is inane). Use this command to fix that:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false`

Comment: I typed `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true` and now it works. Thanks.